# What is the importance of the Krull's principal ideal theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What is the importance of the [Krull's principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) in later study of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry?

Can any one tell me the geometric picture of this theorem?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

It is very closely linked to dimension theory in algebraic geometry, as a proper ideal with only one generator in a polynomial ring in $n$ variables over an algebraically closed field have a zero set of dimension $n-1$ by this theorem. The generalization by induction say that for each new generator, the dimension of the zero set goes down in dimension by at most 1.

As for a more concrete geometric picture, most irreducible real polynomials (I say "most", as the reals are not algebraically closed) in 3 variables will define a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Of course, it might have folds, singularities and self-intersections. Two polynomials usually define one or more curves (but might define a surface if one polynomial's zero set is entirely contained in the other's), while three usually defines single points.

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur. I pointed my question out on my own when I continued reading Commutative Algebra book.